# How does the GWT sinkEvent functionality works?

Tags: java, events, gwt

I have a simple GWT setup for testing:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="container" width="500px" height="300px">
    <g:Label ui:field="inner" text="hello"></g:Label>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

With handlers added:

```
container.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        Window.alert("click on container");
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());

inner.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        Window.alert("click on inner");
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Each of these addHandler calls, as we know from the sources,

> DOM.sinkEvents(Element elem, int eventBits)

inside, and the latter, according to docs, *"Sets the current set of events sunk by a given element. These events will be fired to the nearest {@link EventListener} specified on any of the element's parents."*

But in fact, if you click on inner div the click will be fired to its parent div in any of the 3 ways:

- if I have not set any ClickHandlers on child
- if I have set handlers on child
- if I have set the handlers, but cleared the sinking of ClickEvent with

DOM.sinkEvents(inner.getElement(), DOM.getEventsSunk(getElement()) & ~Event.getTypeInt(ClickEvent.getType().getName()));

Why this happens and what is the true role of sinking the events?
Why adding a Handler is related to sinking events, i.e. to firing the same event to parent of the given element?
Is it possible to prevent all handlers, added to the given widget from calling without removing them explicitely? I.e. is there a way to stop processing all events on some widget?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `sinkEvent` is about adding the native event handler on the element, as explained in the [GWT wiki](https://github.com/gwtproject/old_google_code_wiki/blob/master/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks.wiki.md).

What you're seeing is event bubbling, which is how events work in browsers: there are 2 phases when dispatching an event: the capture phase (not implemented in old IEs) allows any ancestor element to catch the event before it reaches its target, then in the bubbling phase the event *bubbles up* the DOM hierarchy. So if you listen for clicks on the `HTMLPanel`, you'll also receive the bubbling click events from the `Label`.

You can prevent that by listening to the event at the `Label` level and calling `stopPropagation()` so it doesn't bubble up to the `HTMLPanel`.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. But if I want to prevent any event from processing even on Label level - looks like all I need is to zero out the sunkEvents via DOM.sinkEvents(label.getElement(), 0), am I right? And I can easily switch it back by adding ClickEvent bitmask, without adding/removing the handlers.

Comment: That'd work but is a big ugly hack! How about just testing in the event handler whether you have some work to do or not (i.e. whether you're disabled or not) ? `sinkEvents` really is an low-level API that should only be used in widgets internals; don't mess with other widgets or you'll likely break them.

Comment: Thats what I did - added if clause in all my events handlers to prevent events from being processed when my widget is disabled. But copy-pasting the same 'if' in 5 handlers doesn't look that good too, actually.. :/

Comment: Link is dead unfortunately.

Comment: Those things happen with 2yo links. Link fixed.