# GWT - SinkEvent ONCLICK is not working

Tags: java, dom, gwt, onclick

I have a problem that I sinked two events `ONMOUSEOVER` and `ONCLICK`. 
My problem is that the `ONMOUSEOVER` get called but `ONCLICK` is not getting fired at all !!

Here is my code sample

```
LIElement elem = Document.get().createLIElement();
        DOM.sinkEvents(elem, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
    DOM.setEventListener(elem, new EventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {


            if (Event.ONCLICK == event.getTypeInt()) {
                           //Not reaching this code block at all !! 
            }
            if (Event.ONMOUSEOVER == event.getTypeInt()) {
                //Everything is working fine here                       
            }

        }
    });
```

This code is working just fine in other part of the system, and I am generating the LIElements dynamically BUT I don't think that this is the problem.

Might it be something related to attaching browser listeners or DOM rendering?

Any help will be appreciated I am chasing this since two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a Widget from scratch (using DOM elements directly, as opposed to simply creating a Composite), the setup for event handling is a bit odd. Generally, it looks something like this:

```
class MyWidget extends Widget {
    public MyWidget() {
        setElement(DOM.createDiv());
        sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
    }

    public void onBrowserEvent(Event evt) {
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(evt)) {
            case Event.ONCLICK:
                // Do something insightful.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

For detailed description have a look at

- [GWT - An explanation of DOM events, memory leaks, and how GWT handles both.](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks)
- [How does the GWT sinkEvent functionality works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004658/how-does-the-gwt-sinkevent-functionality-works)

---

The below sample code is working fine in Firefox and Chrome as well (Not tested for others).

```
final Element desc = Document.get().createLIElement();
SpanElement spanElement = Document.get().createSpanElement();
spanElement.setInnerHTML("Hello");

desc.appendChild(spanElement);

DOM.sinkEvents((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
DOM.setEventListener((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(e)) {
            case Event.ONCLICK:
                System.out.println("click");
                break;
            case Event.ONMOUSEOVER:
                System.out.println("hover");
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still the ONCLICK event is not fired.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with your code. First try it with sample code. only single component added in Root Panel.

Comment: thank you very much, I fixed it. I was by mistake setting the main panel to null instead of hiding it

Comment: Sounds Good. Welcome you.